# Why can't I start the game after it's downloaded?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've just finished downloading Skyrim SE for my Xbox One, but I'm not able to start the game. Every time I want to open the game, it wants to update the game. Unfortunately, the update never starts. Instead I get the message that there was a problem.

My internet works, so I don't think that's the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Interesting, did you try restarting your Xbox?

Comment: I would do a hard reboot (hold down the power button until it turns off) and then try again.  If that doesn't work, you might have to delete it and redownload it.

Answer (score 2):

- You probably just need to **perform a system update for the Xbox**.
  Go to *System* → *Settings* → *Updates & Downloads*, and select '*Console update available*'.
  After that process has finished, try updating Skyrim again.
- Alternatively, you can give reinstalling the game a try.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, this could possibly be a DLC that needs to be downloaded, I have had this problem with my PS4 with multiple games, I try and run it, it says "Cannot download update file." It could be you don't have enough storage, just a glitch with Skyrim, having to download it again, numerous problems, try removing some things from storage and running it again, try reinstalling Skyrim, if these don't work, tell me.